# OpenCL Median Image Filter using Local Work Groups

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, opencl

I have created a branch-less median 3x3 filter and got at around 200 mill per pass with it on a high res image(~4K by 3K) and I figured that i could get a better time if I created the kernel to utilize work groups. Unfortunately the implement tell me what I am doing wrong for I would like to know.

```
#define wgs 16
//Work group size
#define cas3(a, b)                              \
    do {                                            \
            float4 x = a;                           \
            int4 c = a> b;                          \
            a.s012 = select(b, a, c).s012;          \
            b.s012 = select(x, b, c).s012;          \
    } while (0)

__kernel void median3x3_rgb( read_only image2d_t src, write_only image2d_t dst) {
    int gx = get_global_id(0), gy = get_global_id(1);
    int lx = get_local_id(0), ly = get_local_id(1);
const sampler_t smp = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |    CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

    if ((gx >= get_image_width(dst)) | (gy >= get_image_height(dst)))
            return;

__local float4 la[wgs+2][wgs+2];

la[lx+1][ly+1] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx,gy));    

if(lx == 0){
    la[lx][ly+1] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx-1,gy));
    if(ly == 0)
        la[lx+1][ly] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx-1,gy));
    if(ly == wgs)
        la[lx+1][ly+2] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx+1,gy));
}
else if(lx == wgs){
    la[lx+2][ly+1] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx+1,gy));
    if(ly == 0)
        la[lx+1][ly] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx-1,gy));
    if(ly == wgs)
        la[lx+1][ly+2] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx+1,gy));
}
else if(ly == 0)
    la[lx+1][ly] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx-1,gy));
else if(ly == wgs)
    la[lx+1][ly+2] = read_imagef(src,smp,(int2)(gx+1,gy));


barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); //----------------------- mem barrier

    float4 s0 = la[ lx-1][ly-1 ];
    float4 s1 = la[ lx  ][ly-1 ];
    float4 s2 = la[ lx+1][ly-1 ];
    float4 s3 = la[ lx-1][ly   ];
    float4 s4 = la[ lx  ][ly   ];
    float4 s5 = la[ lx+1][ly   ];
    float4 s6 = la[ lx-1][ly+1 ];
    float4 s7 = la[ lx  ][ly+1 ];
    float4 s8 = la[ lx+1][ly+1 ];
```

Starting the sorting 
this area works fine don't worry about it

```
    // stage0
    cas3(s1, s2);
    cas3(s4, s5);
    cas3(s7, s8);

    // 1
    cas3(s0, s1);
    cas3(s3, s4);
    cas3(s6, s7);

    // 2
    cas3(s1, s2);
    cas3(s4, s5);
    cas3(s7, s8);

    // 3/4
    cas3(s3, s6);
    cas3(s4, s7);
    cas3(s5, s8);
    cas3(s0, s3);

    cas3(s1, s4);
    cas3(s2, s5);
    cas3(s3, s6);

    cas3(s4, s7);
    cas3(s1, s3);

    cas3(s2, s6);
    cas3(s2, s3);
    cas3(s4, s6);

    cas3(s3, s4);
```

Ending the sorting

```
    write_imagef(dst, (int2) (gx, gy), s4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of random suggestions to experiment:

- early return should be used with caution when there is a barrier later: **all** work items in a work group should execute the barrier, and your kernel will hang if some work items already returned.
- texture cache in this context is usually at least as fast as local memory. Try replacing s0,...,s8 initialization with simple read_imagef calls.  Then experiment with different work group dimensions.

On what hardware are you running?

Comment: I am running it on a i7 and a 660m